# Best practices with ASP.NET MVC view models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I ask myself how do I create a view model correctly.

For instance, I have an edit view with some text boxes and a dropdownlist.

Should I separate the dropdown list into a new view model or shoud the edit view have one viewmodel with a list for the dropdownlist?

Or generally speaking, should I separate special input fields in separate view models?

When should a view have more than one view model and when not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no clear rule of how to create and organize your view models correctly. Your question is too vague to be answered because you provided too little context.

I usually group view models according to functional blocks/parts of the screen they represent. So for example imagine that you have a complex form composed of multiple sections/fieldsets like contact details, delivery address, billing information, etc... An address could be composed of street, zip, city and country dropdown. I would create an address view model containing those four properties so that it can be reused in multiple views/partial views. This will also make validation easier as dependent properties will be packed into the same view model like validate for example that the given zip corresponds to the city and that the city belongs to the selected country.

> For instance, I have an edit view with
>   some text boxes and a dropdownlist.
>
> Should I separate the dropdown list
>   into a new view model or shoud the
>   edit view have one viewmodel with a
>   list for the dropdownlist?

I would say no, if those fields are somehow functionally related.

Conclusion: you will have to find the right balance between having a view model per field on the screen and having a single view model per application.

Comment: Regarding creating reusable sub viewmodels you mentioned - what if you change your Address viewmodel because you needed to modify it for only one specific view - the change will affect other views that use the Address viewmodel even though you indented to change only one view?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the approach of one view model per view/partial view. This is in my opinion the best  approach if you believe the view model's single purpose should be modeling the view. This paradigm also supports the use of strongly typed views thus providing compile time error checking for your views model binding and you get the added benefit of intellisense. In the scenarios where you want to re-use some logic, I find it can often be satisfied by re-factoring the view into partial views and providing these partials with their own view models. It should be emphasized that no domain logic should  exists in your view models as it really belongs in a domain model.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the dropdown list into new view model if you want to be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

You would generally want to use ViewModel pattern if you want to store the data used by the typed view. For UI specific logic and details, a ViewHelper pattern would be more suited.

For some discussion on ViewModel see this article. http://theminimalistdeveloper.com/2010/08/21/why-when-and-how-to-use-typed-views-and-viewmodel-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: I glanced through the article and I am wondering why there is a Model directory and a ViewModel directory? The Model direcotry is for the view models. The mentioned Model directory looks like the domain model/ object model. So what they did is to create a view model that consists of two domain objects.

Comment: @Rookian. Yes you are correct. ViewModel is for ViewModels while Model is for domain/business models.